# Bandwith usage on Mac

Tags: macos, data-transfer

I am using iStat Menus for years now. I have just realized the upload speed does not match the actual processes. I am just uploading to google drive and I have zero other ongoing process that consumes the upload bandwidth which can be seen on the attached screenshot. Can someone chime in and comment..

[image]

Comment: What do you want to know @koray?

Comment: @ankii googleDrive shows as 3,1MB/s but the wifi interface shows 6.39MB/s... it should be equal or close to equal since there are not other processes using the upload bandwidth ? Rite ?

Comment: What about the process right below it, *AMPDeviceD...* that has 6MB and the aggregate (WiFi) is 6,3MB.  The WiFi graph  doesn’t just measure Google Drive, it’s supposed to show a representation of all traffic and it appears to not work.  What did the developer say?  It seems to be a bug

Comment: I maintain that all these 'monitor' apps - Little Snitch, etc - do nothing except pour fuel on the fire of unnecessary anxiety about things your computer is supposed to be doing. 99.999% of the time, everything is fine.

Comment: @Allan AMPDevice is showing 6KB/s still does not add up to 6.39 MB/s

Comment: My guess is that in the Wifi section the values shown are the average throughput for the entire range of the graph shown.  And in the Processes section the values shown are the current throughput for each process.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing @benwiggy said about these apps.  You installed a *paid* app ($10USD) and it gives you conflicting info that gets your "worry meter" operating in overdrive and your first action is to ask the community their thoughts...  well, again, *what did the developer say?*   On a side note and out of curiosity, why exactly did you get this app?  What were you hoping to monitor?